# How to Bind DropDown from Different Tables

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

View

```
@model IEnumerable<PinkPearl.Models.GenerateTicket_Details>
```

First dropdown:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AccountDetails", "Index", FormMethod.Post, new { }))
{
     @Html.DropDownList("Value", new SelectList(ViewBag.MyCustomCollection as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "TicketNo", "TicketNo"),"Ticket No", new { @class = "collection", name = "Value", onchange = "jsFunction()" })
```

Second dropdown:

```
     @Html.DropDownList("GenerateBy", new SelectList(ViewBag.MyCustomCollection as  System.Collections.IEnumerable, "GenerateBy", "GenerateBy"),"Generate By", new { @class = "collection", name = "GenerateBy" })
}
```

Controller:

```
 List<GenerateTicket_Details> bk = new List<GenerateTicket_Details>();

 // select data from database and return in ViewBag
 ViewBag.MyCustomCollection = bk;
 return View(bk);
```

Model:

```
public class GenerateTicket_Details
{
    public List<SelectListItem> RateTable { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TicketNo { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string ArrDate { get; set; }
    public string ArrTime { get; set; }
    public string ArrDateTime { get; set; }
    public string quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public decimal Refund { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }
    public string GenerateBy { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> UserMaster { get; set; }
}
```

I want to show both dropdowns **Value, GenerateBy** bound in the same view by using same `ActionResult`. Can someone send me in the right direction?

Comment: What's the mean  `from Different Tables` on the question title?

Comment: Two Different Tables means Table1 and Table2 i want to bind 'TicketNo' in First Dropdown from table1 and  'GenrateBy' in second Dropdown  from table 2

Comment: Did you try to use Two `ViewBag` for two DropdownList ?

Comment: Whats the problem, your code should work fine. Also you need to remove this because you are not passing no model to your view `@model IEnumerable<PinkPearl.Models.GenerateTicket_Details>`. You are using `ViewBag`

Comment: @dshih you do not need 2 viewbags.